# Perl WebService::Blogger

Tags: perl, cpan, blogger

I've been trying to use the Perl module WebService::Blogger (from CPAN) to connect to my blogger account, but I'm having problem creating a new object of the WebService::Blogger class. When I call the new constructor like the example given in the documentation:

```
WebService::Blogger->new(login_id=>'username', password=>'password');
```

I get an error saying that:

> Attribute (password) is required.

However, if I save the details in the ~/.www_blogger_rc, it works fine. But once I remove it, it starts giving me this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the code, and it appears to be a bug in the BUILDARGS method of WebService::Blogger.  It handles loading the login information from a file, but it doesn't call the base class BUILDARGS to handle parameters passed to `new`.

As a result, `WebService::Blogger->new(login_id=>'username', password=>'password');` is equivalent to `WebService::Blogger->new();`, since BUILDARGS discarded the parameters.

Please [report the bug](http://rt.cpan.org/NoAuth/ReportBug.html?Queue=WebService-Blogger).

Comment: Done, and thanks, it helps a lot now that I know what to look for.

Comment: @Asad Jibran Ahmed, you don't seem to have reported the bug to the author.  It's not listed in the [bug queue](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=WebService-Blogger).

Comment: I thought it would be better to submit a patch along with the bug report as well. Just waiting until I get it working.

Comment: @Asad Jibran Ahmed, I recommend reporting the bug immediately.  It helps others know about the problem, and the author can likely fix it faster than you can, as he's more familiar with the code.  You can say you're working on a patch, and then add it to the bug report if & when you get it working.